# git unable to push using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

Git IDE Eclipse neon

I am using eclipse neon using project History view i am trying to push my local changes into remote/origin. here i attached my pushing image screens for the references.
[image] Next push image screen is location of remote.
[image] in the second image i used options **(Re-base commits of local branch onto upstream)** so here what is the issue means my friend already he done single push before mine. 
So now my question is here while i am pushing why remote changes not re-basing with mine ? so i am unable to push my changes here i am getting error non-fast-forward why ?

Pull window image:[image]

Could you please help on this ?

Comment: Those are options for pulling, so you need to pull first which will rebase properly and then push.

Comment: Ok i Agree with your point.
So why these above two options is required here when doing a pull.
For example now i am going to attach pull image, same above two options also available here. but why from push window its not working ?

Comment: It's not required, you could uncheck the box for *"configure upstream for push and pull"* It's just a GUI wrapper for `git config branch.<name>.rebase true`

Comment: Thanks lot Mr.jeff.
i was unchecked option configure upstream for push and pull.
I added it my config rebase = true.